# Paperclip image sizes not consistent in display?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Here is how i am displaying my images and finding out that they are not consistent. I have two keys that i have created in the model respectively, :thumb and :test.

```
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:thumb), class:"img-thumbnail" %>
                <%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:test), class:"img-thumbnail" %></br>
                 <%= post.user.name %>
            </h3>
        </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= post.content %></br>
        <%= image_tag post.avatar.url(:medium) %></br>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My user Model
As you can see, i have the sizes specified yet it the images do not confine to these bounds. I am very confused as to why i set up these sizes in the model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :posts

  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                                    styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>", test: "64x64>" }, 
                                    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not due to the `img-thumbnail` CSS class? Assuming this is Bootstrap, that class sets a style of `max-width: 100%` on the image. Try removing that, or using your browser's inspector to see the actual image size (right click image and choose 'Inspect' in Chrome it will show the actual and rendered size of the image in a tooltip).

Comment: So i removed the bootstrap class and as per your instruction I inspected it and they were indeed different sizes. The images i uploaded to the site were also different but it was to my understanding that the images would be resized to fit the parameters that I assigned in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, you have specified the size as `100X100>`. The `>` operation will only shrink images that are larger than 100pixels and maintain the aspect ratio.

If you want your images to be exactly `100X100` pixels, set up the models without the `>` operator.

Paperclip uses Imagemagick to resize images, and you can read more about it [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink).